# Who are the "root" owners of assets?

Tags: stocks, assets

I'm trying to make a bit of sense of ownership of companies. You mostly have a chain of ownership like Company A is partially owned by Company B, who is partially owned by Investment Fund C, who is partially owned by Investment Firm D, who is partially owned by Bank E, etc. If one would trace the "root" owners of all companies in the world, where would one get?

1. Human individual like you and me (or richer counterparts)
2. Abstract entities like companies or states
3. Nowhere, companies often own each-other

Comment: The Economist periodically runs an article on cross holding examples.  E.g. Fiat and most of corporate Japan.   I'll see if I can find some links.

Answer (score 3):

Any company must have owner(s) or shareholder(s).  Those owner(s) can be other already existing companies, states, or individuals.  However, eventually up the tree companies fall out - since a company can't exist without an owner.  For example, Berkshire Hathaway owns a lot of other companies - but it in turn is owned by its shareholders.

States, however, can own corporations (in socialism, this is quite common).  You can argue whether a state is technically comprised of individuals or not; that's a meaningless distinction in my book.  You also have state-controlled organizations, such as [CalPers](https://www.calpers.ca.gov/), one of the largest stockholding entities in the US (The California Public Employees' Retirement System).

So - mostly individuals, but with states also owning companies in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Regular companies have shareholders, so you can't really count them as root owners. Even if two companies own bits of each other this still generally holds since each time round the cycle you apportion more of the ownership to other owners.

So afaict that leaves three categories of "root owner".

1. Individuals
2. States
3. Charities, nonprofits and similar entities.

I have no idea if anyone has documented the relative balance of these different categories.

Comment: Charities/etc. would still be incorporated and still "belong" to people, in some fashion (their board, likely).  Their funds can't be dispersed to those people, but they still control the charity and own it for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Add "estates and trusts", perhaps.